# KeyStroke class as a key in HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, keystroke

Several answers regarding overriding equals() and hashCode() describe the need for both and the application of using them as keys in a HashMap in Java. My question is, is the Java KeyStroke class safe to put as a key in a HashMap? Further, so I'm not annoying and continue to ask these questions, how would one find out if a provided class (I think KeyStroke is provided by Swing) is safe to use in this context...i.e. overrides equals() and hashCode()?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to see if `equals` and `hashCode` are overridden is to take a look at the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/KeyStroke.html). `hashCode` and `equals` are not overridden in `KeyStroke`, but they are in `AWTKeyStroke`. In fact, [`AWTKeyStroke#hashCode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/AWTKeyStroke.html#hashCode%28%29) states:

> [this object is] a good choice as the index value in a hash table.

Comment: @Jeffrey: Many thanks! I had tripped over the KeyStroke javadoc, completely missing the AWTKeyStroke extension. Thanks again...

Answer (score 2):

Best if a HashMap key overrides equals and hashCode and is ***immutable***, and if you check the API, KeyStroke is. So it should be fine.